# error: expected unqualified-id before 'if' and 'else' C++

Tags: c++

I can't figure out what is the unqualified id in my code, or how to remedy it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{  
    string x;
    getline(cin, x);
}

if (x == 1) {
    cout << "x is 1";
}

else if (x == 2) {
    cout << "x is 2";
}

else {
    cout << "value of x unknown";
}
```

old code above.   new code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()

 {
     string mystr;
     int number;
    cout << "pick a number ";
    getline (cin, mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> number;

if (number == 1) 
  cout << "x is 1";

else if (number == 2) 
  cout << "x is 2";

else 
  cout << "its not one or 2";
}
```

does this need any improvements? Appreciate all the help and for helping me.

Comment: The `}` in `getline (cin, x);}`

Comment: You can't put instructions outside any function. Only declarations/definitions can go there.

Comment: Voted to close as typographical error. @jamms69: if your reputation score allows it (SO can sometimes be finicky about that), please just delete the question. That will save some effort. Oh no! Someone *answered* it. Well.

Comment: The message means that the compiler is lost. @NickyC gives the reason.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and answer and showing me where i slipped up. But now there is this huge wall of error text Im ,using C++ shell if that is any help

Comment: @Alf  sorry about that, Im a new user. ill make sure it wont happen again in the future.

Comment: Thanks guys for pushing me in the right direction.i figured out my mistake and definitely improved the code but if anybody has any advice or constructive criticism it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int main ()
{  
    string x;
    getline(cin, x);
} // <-- ERRONEOUS!

if (x == 1) {
...
```

You are terminating `main()` prematurely, causing the rest of your code to be outside of any function, thus the compiler error.  You need to move that erroneous `}` to the end of `main()` instead.

After you make that change, you get the `operator==()` errors because you cannot compare a `string` to an `int` using the `==` operator.  You need to change the `int` values into strings and then compare those instead.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{  
    string x;
    getline(cin, x);

    if (x == "1") {
        cout << "x is 1";
    }

    else if (x == "2") {
        cout << "x is 2";
    }

    else {
        cout << "value of x unknown";
    }

    return 0; // <-- don't forget this

} // <-- brace moved here
```

If you really want to compare numeric values, you need to convert the value of `x` into an `int` variable first (and don't forget error checking):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstring>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{  
    string x;

    if (!getline(cin, x)) {
        cout << "unable to read x";
    }
    else {
        istringstream iss(x);
        int value;

        if (!(iss >> value)) {
            cout << "x is not a number";
        }

        else if (value == 1) {
            cout << "x is 1";
        }

        else if (value == "2") {
            cout << "x is 2";
        }

        else {
            cout << "value of x unknown";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```